# Fire base auth to redirect page based on user

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently first year student and I am creating web application. I have manage to redirect the page to the main menu using `window.location = ""`.

However, I want multiple redirect pages such as admin user can access to their own page as well as the new user can go to their page and finally the employee would go to their own page.

My current functions are in js file and main codes are in HTML file. Can someone help me please?

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    window.location = "main.html"

    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if(user != null){
      var email_id = user.email;
    }

  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    document.getElementById("user_div").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("login_div").style.display = "block";
  }
});

function login(){

  var userEmail = document.getElementById("email_field").value;
  var userPass = document.getElementById("password_field").value;

  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPass).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    window.alert("Error : " + errorMessage);

    // ...
  });
}

function logout(){
  firebase.auth().signOut();
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Diabetes Login</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,600,700" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style4.css" />
</head>
<body>

  <div id="login_div" class="main-div">
    <h3>Welcome to Diabetes log</h3>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email..." id="email_field" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." id="password_field" />

    <button onclick="login()">Login to Account</button>
  </div>

  <div id="user_div" class="loggedin-div">
    <h3>Welcome User</h3>
    <p id="user_para"> You're currently logged in.</p>
    <button onclick="logout()">Logout</button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Initialize Firebase
    var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBHP48kjdW-YzKCdZA_-TcVnni-NlCZZ8Q",
    authDomain: "diabetesapp-ee8fa.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://diabetesapp-ee8fa.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "diabetesapp-ee8fa",
    storageBucket: "diabetesapp-ee8fa.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "769133104242"
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  </script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that your real API key??

Comment: yeah it uni project,so its ok, u can use it its free